How to connect lambda job with event bridge to trigger an ecs task?
How to connect lambda job with event bridge to trigger an ecs task? I am not sure whether there is a direct integration and if so how to add input and credentials?
I have check the aws docs but I am not clear on how to do this.

Do you want EventBridge to trigger a Lambda function, and then have Lambda trigger an ECS task (which seems reasonable)? Or do you want Lambda to add an event to EventBridge, that will then trigger an ECS task (in which case, I have no idea why you would want to use EventBridge instead of just having Lambda trigger the ECS task directly)? Please be as specific as possible in your question.

I want to do the first scenario. But I was checking whether its possible with out a lambda

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
